# Kendo Grid change event firing issue(fired two times when i click one row)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, user-interface, kendo-ui

Kendo ui  grid 
I attached the change event on grid,but every time it alert twice when i click one row.

```
function onChange(arg) {
    var selected = $.map(this.select(), function (item) {
        return $(item).text();
    });
    alert(selected.join(", "));
}
```

the grid code

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ETender.Mvc.Models.Region>()
                .Name("country")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(r => r.ID);
                        columns.Bound(r => r.CNAME);
                        columns.Bound(r => r.ENAME);
                    })
                    .Sortable()
                    //.Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Virtual(false).Height(500))
                    .Selectable()
                    .Pageable()
                    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
                    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true)) 
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .ServerOperation(true)
                        .Events(ev => ev.Error("loadError"))
                        .Model(m =>
                        {
                            m.Id(p => p.ID);
                            m.Field(p => p.ID).Editable(false);
                        })
                        .Read(read => read.Action("GetRegionList", "Region")
                            .Data("function() { return {         CountryID:'0',ProvinceID:'0',CityID:'0',RegionType: 'Country'}; }")
                            )
                    )
                     .Events(events => events.Change("onChange"))

                )
```

Who have the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Basically this behavior is caused by using "alert" method for debugging purposes - please note that this is not recommended because it can lead to unexpected behavior when interacting with focusing elements. After replacing the "alert" method and with "debugger" command or "console.log()" function the change event will work as expected.

Comment: sorry Vlad...the event still fires twice with console.log(). window.alert() has nothing to do with it.